# create a offline/local highscore database for a simple iphone game and use it!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite, core-data

I am a beginner in iOS development and am trying to create a offline/local highscore database for a simple iphone game and use it.

this would be my first time to create and use a database on a ios device

i know sql

i don't care if i would directly use sqlite3 or core data

the database should be arranged by highscore

my game is simple and using the "moving UIImageviews" principe. It is finished, it just needs a highscorelist.

I searched the web for hours, but i didn't understand how core data works or how to use a sqlite database :( (i created it but didn't get how to use it in the code)

maybe this is the stupidest question you have ever heard … but please still help me. I BEGG YOU!

sincerly a0down

Comment: Do you really need SQL for this? If it's just a highscore list for the iPhone itself it would probably not need more than a few entries, max. 10 perhaps. You could implement this much easier just by using NSArrays and NSDictionaries.

Comment: i think this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started explaines everything to me that i need to know.